# NPM TypeORM - "Error: Duplicate migrations" after modifying/deleting migration file

Tags: javascript, database, npm, migration, typeorm

I previously add a column to an existing table using, `npm run migration:generate <filename>`.

However, I later realized that I misspelled the column name so I wanted to rename the column. (showComission -> showCommission)

Since it was just in a local environment, I modified the column name on the migration file and run `npm run migration:run`.

The duplicated migration error occurred and here's the log.

**addShowCommissionToCorporationProfile1643792138368 is the modified export class name.

> typeorm migration:run
>
> query: SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE
> `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'abc' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'migrations'
>
> query: SELECT * FROM `abc`.`migrations` `migrations` ORDER BY `id` DESC
>
> Error during migration run:
> Error: Duplicate migrations: addShowCommissionToCorporationProfile1643792138368
>
> ```
> at MigrationExecutor.checkForDuplicateMigrations
> at MigrationExecutor.getMigrations
> at MigrationExecutor.<anonymous> 
> at step 
> at Object.next 
> at fulfilled 
> at processTicksAndRejections npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! abc-api@1.0.0 migration:run: `typeorm migration:run`
> ```
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the abc-api@1.0.0
> migration:run script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
> npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

After that I try to revert `npm run migration:revert`, but the exact same error occurred. So instead, I changed the migration file back to its initial state and use `npm run migration:generate --filename` to create migration file for renaming the column but the same error stills occurred.
Lastly, I deleted newly created migration file and run only the original migration file (initial state) and run migration again, but the same error stills occurred.

Can anyone advise me how could I fixed this mess?

I just wanted to rename the column...

Please let me know if you need any additional info or more clarification about the situation.

Appreciate all your helps.

Comment: have you find any solution?, I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same error on a NestJS project. The solution for me was to delete the dist folder, and rebuild the project, afterwards I could run the new migration.

Explanation: We just changed the project structure recently, and moved the migrations to a different folder. However, Nest has a weird "bug": when we move files, it rebuilds the part of the project where we moved the file, but not necessarily the part of the project from where we removed it. Hence the duplicate migrations in this case. When we rebuild the whole thing, there are no longer duplicate migrations in the build.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue and was surprised by lack of Google results on this issue.

I am also using it for a NestJS application, but deleting `dist` folder and running a build again (as suggested in other answers) didn't help.

Turned out the reason was that I used an index file in the migrations folder which exported the migrations in addition to the migration files themselves. So when TypeORM scans the project for migrations (in case you provide a regex for migration files) it imports it twice - from the migration itself and from the index file.

So for a case like this you have 2 options:

- Delete `index.ts` from the migrations folder
- Change the value of the `migrations` option of your DataSource to use `path/to/migrations/index.{ts,js}` instead of a regex with `*` in the filename. In that case you also need to make sure that new migrations are added to the index file.

Answer (score 0):

I exec npm run build and the problem solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31707156)